# Xcode 14 didn't find framework

Tags: swift, frameworks

After adding the framework to the project, I get an error: 0 __Abort_with_payload
On the computer, the simulation does not run due to an error:
building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS

Solution https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658424 doesn't work.

Added based on this document: https://github.com/Haivision/srt/blob/master/docs/build/build-iOS.md

Testing on iPad 16.3.1
Xcode 14.3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly set up your library search paths as the link said? Double-check in the Build Settings **of your target** under the "Library Search Paths" field.

Also make sure the ["Build Active Architecture Only" flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztjgW.png) in the Build Settings is set to "Yes" for  the Debug configuration.

Comment: [Active Architecture is on](https://imgur.com/HLgOttX)                                                            There are screens from [Library Search Paths](https://imgur.com/iK8IJR5) and from                                                           [Header Search Paths](https://imgur.com/uJ1R2UP)

Comment: Update: [added header search paths](https://imgur.com/OAzpwIA) And now I have more errors. [14 errors](https://imgur.com/clziRDn) 1. While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accessibility.framework/Headers/AXFoundation.h:11: